# Custom BouncingScroll Effect in flutter

Tags: flutter

#### Project

Hi, I was playing around with bouncing scroll physics in flutter, trying to achieve a specific behaviour.

Here is a simple mockup

[image]

BouncingScrollPhysics in flutter create this overscroll effect on top of a listview adding some space in relation to user scroll.

#### Question

Is it possible to extend this behaviour also to the spacing between list view elements? I noticed this kind of behaviour in some ios apps lately and i wanted to understand if this is achievable in flutter.

Hope someone can help with this, it's really cool effect.

Thanks